# Crystal Report XI create Gannt chart by quarter or display x axis in quarters

Tags: crystal-reports

I have just about given up on this one. I thought it would be simple.

I have a database that i need to report on by quarter. It has a project name and implementation date. All I need to do is display the project name and the date in will implement. I have this part working. I need to convert the x axis to display by quarter instead of month year. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Crystal are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a chart grouped by quarter instead of by month, I recommend aggregating the data by quarter before you feed it into Crystal.  Possibly with a temporary Excel file to hold it for you.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple with a Gantt Chart; It requires that you feed it two dates for each record and doesn't *seem* to give any control over the x-axis units or date grouping options, at least that I could see.

Comment: Ryan - That is what I ran in to. I can convert the date into Quarter/Year format, but the Gannt chart will not let me select it as a data element.  I think I am out of luck for this one.